# Add two real numbers ... probably

Tags: code-golf, math, number, arithmetic, open-ended-function

The problem statement here is pretty simple, take two real numbers on the range [0,1) as input and output their sum, with probability 1.

The catch here is that there are a lot of real numbers. There are in fact so many real numbers that it is impossible to fit all of them into any finite data type. As such, any way to input real numbers has to be potentially infinite, and any algorithm that handles arbitrary real numbers cannot consume all of the input.

For this challenge you will input (and output) real numbers as lazy sequence (e.g. stream, generator, lazy list, function) of bits, representing their binary expansion. You can assume that the input will be normalized and will not end in an infinite repetition of `1`.

Even with this special input format it isn't possible to add any two real numbers. Any potential algorithm can be tricked into an infinite loop.

So instead we are going to settle for *almost* working. To "work" on a pair of inputs your program needs to be able to output any bit of the output in finite time. For example, if you output a generator I should be able to read to the 5th bit without the program getting stuck in a loop. Your answer needs to work with probability 1, meaning that the measure of the set of inputs which your program does work needs to have measure 1. The behavior for which the program doesn't work is undefined it can loop forever give an incorrect answer etc. so long as these cases themselves have measure zero.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) the goal is to minimize the size of your source code as measured in bytes.

### Examples

Here are some examples of rational numbers being added. You do not need to support any of these specific numbers.

```
1/3  = 0.01010101010101010...
+
1/5  = 0.00110011001100110...
=
8/15 = 0.10001000100010001...
```

```
3/8  = 0.011000000000000000...
+
3/16 = 0.001100000000000000...
=
9/16 = 0.100100000000000000...
```

```
17/95    = 0.001011011100111101111110101001110001001011011100111101111110101...
+
3/13     = 0.001110110001001110110001001110110001001110110001001110110001001...
=
506/1235 = 0.011010001110001100101111111000100010011010001110001100101111111...
```

Comment: I find the challenge description interesting & tantalizing, but difficult to concretely understand.  Could you add an example to flesh-out "Any potential algorithm can be tricked into an infinite loop", for instance...?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Take for one input 0 followed by a random sequence S of 0s and 1s and 0 followed its complement S' for the other. The sum is 1,0,0,0, but your program will never have enough information to output the first 1.

Comment: @loopywalt It's a little more subtle, the sum is also 0,1,1,1... that is a valid output and the two are equal, however you can't output that either, because if at some point both inputs had a `1` in the same place it would cause a cascade that would fill out the 1s place.  Basically to ever commit to a digit you need to find a place after it that has either a 0 in each or a 1 in each, but that's never true of S and S'.

Comment: A non-random example of S and S' would be 1/3 and 2/3, which are compliments after the 1s place.

Comment: Instead of two separate generator/stream inputs `a` and `b`, may we instead take a single generator/stream as input whose elements are `a[0], b[0], a[1], b[1], ...`?

Comment: Is the number 1 valid?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien That's alright.

Comment: @Joao-3 There's no need to support any specific numbers, as long as the exceptions have finite measure, it is valid. So no valid algorithm can be made invalid by not supporting 1, and no invalid algorithm can be made valid by supporting 1.  The same can be said for any number e.g. 1/2, pi/4 etc.

Comment: I'm still struggling to get my head around this, particularly after reading @loopywalt 's answer below.  Aren't there an infinite number of pairs of inputs for which pairs of bits never match, and so need to be exceptions...?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I think there is a bit of not fully trivial measure theory buried in this question. If the inputs only match at finitely many places then the normalised representation of their sum is finite. Finitely representable numbers are a subset of rationals and the rationals are known to have Lebesgue measure zero. It doesn't end there, because what we really need to measure is the preimage of this i.e. all pairs that sum to finitely represented numbers. This preimage is a bunch of parallel lines within the plane. This still has measure zero,but my maths is too rusty for a good reason.

Comment: @loopywalt Let's say that for a given \$x\$, the measure of exceptions that cannot be added with \$x\$ is \$m(x)\$. Then the total measure of pairs of numbers which cannot be added is \$\int_{(0,1)}m\$. If we fix one of the inputs \$x\$, the number of inputs which only match \$x\$ at finitely many places is countable and thus measure zero.  So \$m(x)=0\$ and thus \$\int_{(0,1)}m=0\$ so the exceptions have measure zero.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen A more intuitive way to go about this is to assume two random independent and uniform streams of bits.  What is the chance they will never output the same value? Well it's 1/2 for the first bit 1/2 for the second etc. so it converges to 0. The chance two random streams will never output the same bit is zero.  Now the chance they will only output finitely many equal bits is also zero, since you can ask, what is the chance that bit 1 is the same and all after are unequal, what is the chance that bit 2 is the same and all after are unequal ... each of these is 0. So the sum is 0.

Comment: I am tempted by Haskell's `zipWith(+)`, but then there is carry.

Comment: Re: the 3rd test-case: isn't 17/95 + 3/13 equal to 506/1235, not 376/1235?  Or am I missing something again...?

Comment: I suppose _no_ such algorithm supports a case where the true sum (as real numbers) is `9/16`, as in the given example `3/8 + 3/16`. Because reading a finite portion of each addend, you can never figure out what digit (bit) to output on the 4th place after the period. For an example where both addends have unique binary expansion, but the sum is still `9/16`, take `7/24 + 13/48`. Certainly, you can also have neither addend periodic and still reach sum `9/16`, as in the example `(√2)/16 + (9-√2)/16`.

Answer (score 14):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 75 bytes

```python
def f(*I,n=0):
 for a,b in zip(*I):yield from[a,*n*[1^a]][:-(n:=1+n*(a^b))]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVBBasMwELznFXtcqZtiQw_FkAeUPkEoRXYksmCvhKJC3a_0kkv7lP6hv6mcONBT97Yzw-zMfnyluRyjnM-fryVsH3-eDz5AQP1EsmtUt4EQMzjqgQXeOVVCdTP78QAhx8k40qJNu3fWmm6L0u3aO9Ho9r1SdrX8XpTAxecS43gCnlLMBfTmj7XBySUU_1ZomIfRX9bsk3eFsKFW1aF_JatIEQ5Hx4KmApauPDYVv8D3S5aXJYvrq8VK3y7Y2jdlloKaTyMPHgPWgIoeqsG1ze1Rvw)

Takes two iterables and returns one.

### How?

Count bits that differ between the inputs without outputting anything until an equal bit is encountered. Output this bit followed by counter times its complement. Reset counter and start over.

Answer (score 5):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), <del>222</del> 199 bytes

```rust
|a:Box<dyn Iterator<Item=usize>>,b:Box<dyn Iterator<Item=usize>>|a.zip(b).scan(0,|z,(e,f)|Some(if e==f{let q=*z;*z=0;(e..=e).chain((1-e..2-e).cycle().take(q)).collect()}else{*z+=1;vec![]})).flatten()
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lY9NTsMwEIX3OYXb1bg4UcMKOXGQ2HWNxKaqKjcdiwjHaRMHaH5OwqYLuEHvwBm4DQ6BihUStjzjmbGe3_fyWtaVPZ6UIbnMDFDSehotUUSQt9oq_-rjvZP8pniOtwdDFhZLaYsydpdc1FXWYJKwzd_zTgZNtoMNDapUGpizrmGATNHutsgRMkVQCNUO3-7FrIlmjZhHgEEgkAbp_WALQt_Vl_7QOKQagQZWPiDsqWsUWmNqgfaoK2xnzYUIo0dMJ8tV78ZKS2vRkX3jnCLP25WZsdpMYNry637KiAKPuOUwODf4BAtjix8Wzt3jYp25EpYhC9n86wxxzG6vKGX_UAh_KYRnBe_Mwnl8h2m8ThKg1PntR-_H45g_AQ)

Just the type declaration of a iterator is already longer than some of the answers here :(

Comment: By moving the type declarations into the header you can save quite a few bytes: [139 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lZBNTsMwEIX3OYXb1Tg4UcMKOXGQWCB1jcSmqio3HYsI12kTF2h-TsAR2HQBN-AyvU0dAhUrJGzZ45knPX3Pb-_lrrKHY6EMWcvcACWNp9ESxYkycFO8JKu9IVOLpbRFmbjHWuyqvMY0ZeRPmZIgJZVdcZ47mfNbLa1FkyxSIsjHzqrg6vjaSrZsZVjnG1jSsMqkgQlrawbIFG3vijVCrggKoZqeaiv8OvZrMYkBw1AgDbOHnhqiwPWXQT_YZxqBhlY-ImypGxRaY2aBdqgrbPz6QkTxE2aj2bxzshqwgH4jfcaetylzY7UZwbjh192YEQUeccvl5dzgM0yNLX5Cu3yuW_QhYRaxiE2-Tn8P1e05pewfDtEvh-js4J2zcJ7cY-Z-MgVKHW83sB8OQz0B).

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript, 103 <strike>104</strike> <strike>105</strike> bytes

```javascript
function*g(a){for(;;){for(i=0;(A=a.next().value)!=a.next().value;)i++;yield*[A,...Array(i).fill(+!A)]}}
```

More nicely formatted:

```javascript
function*g(a){
    for(;;){
        for(i=0;(A=a.next().value)!=a.next().value;) i++;
        yield A;
        yield* Array(i).fill(+!A)
    }
}
```

Expects a generator function which yields the bits of the numbers to be added, interleaved.

Comment: You can use `for(;;)` instead of `while(1)` for -1 byte.

Comment: Ah, of course, thanks! @ConorO'Brien

Comment: I think you can save another byte by using a single yield: `yield*[A,...Array(i).fill(+!A)]`

Comment: @ConorO'Brien, Yep, you're right.  I had previously been yielding from another generator, and spread syntax doesn't seem to get values one at a time. (So it wasn't an option)

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
ＦＮ≔⁺ＮＮθＮηＷ⁻ηＮＮηＩ﹪⁺θη²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQ1NTwbG4ODM9TyMgp7QYVUpHAVWljkKhpjUXslgGkF@ekZmTqqDhm5kH1J@BrkdTAV19QFFmXomGc2JxiYZvfkppTj7E5kIdhQygDUZALdb//xspGIChIRCCyf@6ZTkA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as `n` (1-indexed) and in interactive mode will prompt for interleaved input bits until it knows what value the `n`th output bit is but on TIO you just have to provide enough bits (if there aren't enough you'll see a prompt but the program will just halt). Explanation:

```
ＦＮ≔⁺ＮＮθ
```

Input `n` pairs of bits but only keep the sum of the last pair.

```
ＮηＷ⁻ηＮＮη
```

Input further pairs of bits until two match.

```
Ｉ﹪⁺θη²
```

Add the matching bit to the sum from earlier and reduce modulo `2`.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>62</s> 60 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to pajonk*

```r
{t=0
\(x,y){u=t
t<<-`if`(x-y,t+1,0)
if(x==y)c(x,rep(!x,u))}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZFPTsUgEMbjsnOKGjdMpAnsjCknUfNe7StKYnjPliaQpidxUxcewaUH0dMI_ZPQxry4YJiBb358wNt7PXwWh8PuUemidrvKngrdqKMWH62R2c133hnB4J5Y6rBrhQGT59leyT2xmaPmmlOGoCSxQjgsvayuTuTS0hax7yfGz8WXqRojZKtL49GBRX2BHST-MNH1kMhjTVSqdMpvXyr9ZJ6JxbA_CkriY-gg9k49UOcDIiT92A49gG2qV5GmJWGUUT6OJYZ5yXiULRVbKfxd3JrFIx7bqs-vI1xN7lnkiK10LGJs3a3ICOEJSbgoDQ7pX3-G0UvMXW5Tz45m9v-o0y8OwzT_Ag)

Port of [loopy walt's Python approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260289/95126).

Function that accepts sequential pairs of bits from the two numbers to be added as input to successive calls, and gives output when it can, otherwise outputs nothing.  So the full output is the concatenated output of successive calls.
Input corresponds to the bits *after* the binary point, output begins with a single bit *before* the binary point, followed by all bits *after* the binary point (since we need to one more bit in case the two input numbers add-up to greater-than one).

Unfortunately my maths isn't good enough to determine when an infinite number of infinitely-small values sum to a finite value [or to zero](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/260284/add-two-real-numbers-probably#comment573045_260284), so I'm blindly trusting that this approach is valid...

Comment: Are the newlines before `u=t` and `}}` necessary?

Comment: @pajonk - Of course not.  What on earth was i thinking?  Doh.  Thanks.